# Intraweb 14.1.5 Standalone server application not working in delphi xe5

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5, intraweb

I am using intraweb 14.1.5 in Delphi xe5. Default Intraweb application with TIWStart.Execute(true) command works properly, it show default server GUI but when I am using  IWstandaloneserver component and button on VCL form and at button onclick event call standaloneserver.run that time it open browser but not showing Intraweb page, it show "Internet Explorer cannot display the webpage". Same project when I try in delphi 2007 with intraweb 10 version it work properly with using IWStandaloneServer component . Is there any extra property need to be set in server controller page in delphi XE5? bec some properties are missing in new intraweb version as compare to older version.

Comment: Have you verified with netstat that the server is running and listening?

Comment: I checked in netstat server ip port did not there , server is not running

Comment: This is a custom stand alone demo, and works perfectly with all IW 14 versions. Do you have a IW form set as main form?
https://iwdemos.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Atozed Demos/XIV/Delphi/CustomStandAlone

Comment: Yes Alexandre , IW form is initialize as main. I think issue is in stand alone server or in server controller page bec it is not showing running or listening in netstat

Comment: thank you Alexandre, Its working now

Comment: after write IW.Server.Indy file in uses and IWStandAloneServer1.Start(TSaServerIndy);

Comment: After 7 years I'm facing same issue now .. any answer?